Merging a python package into one script file
I'm trying to merge all the files of a python package scripts+binaries into one script. I found this repo that does that: https://github.com/pagekite/PyBreeder
but it's an old repo and was written originally for python2, I found a PR that was written by another guy that fixed some errors for python3, but still it doesn't work for me.
here's the current working PR in github: PyBreeder
It runs and generates one script file.
but after running the generated script, I get this error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
This is the generated script, you don't need to download the pybreeder repo to run it:
#!/usr/bin/python

import base64, os, sys, zlib
try:
    import io as StringIO
except ImportError:
    import StringIO
if sys.version_info >= (999, 3, 4):
    from importlib.util import module_from_spec as new_module
else:
    import warnings
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)
        from imp import new_module
__FILES = {}
__builtin_open = open
__os_path_exists, __os_path_getsize = os.path.exists, os.path.getsize
def __comb_open(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    if filename in __FILES:
        return StringIO.StringIO(__FILES[filename])
    else:
        return __builtin_open(filename, *args, **kwargs)
def __comb_exists(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    if filename in __FILES:
        return True
    else:
        return __os_path_exists(filename, *args, **kwargs)
def __comb_getsize(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    if filename in __FILES:
        return len(__FILES[filename])
    else:
        return __os_path_getsize(filename, *args, **kwargs)
if 'b64decode' in dir(base64):
    __b64d = base64.b64decode
else:
    __b64d = base64.decodestring
open = __comb_open
os.path.exists = __comb_exists
os.path.getsize = __comb_getsize
sys.path[0:0] = ['.SELF/']

###############################################################################
__FILES[".SELF/trying/__init__.py"] = """\
from .app import *
"""
m = sys.modules["trying"] = new_module("trying")
m.__file__ = "trying/__init__.py"
m.open = __comb_open
exec(__FILES[".SELF/trying/__init__.py"], m.__dict__)

###############################################################################

def hello():
    print("nice")


#EOF#

Here's how you can recreate a simple example:
I created a directory called trying with two files: __init__.py and app.py for example.
in __init__.py:
from .app import *

and in app.py:
def hello():
    print("nice")

and run that PyBreeder like this: python breeder.py trying/
Note: It will print the generated script to terminal, so do this if you want to save it to a file: python breeder.py trying/ > generated.py

Why do you want to do this?  What's the point?

i can merge a package into one file and add it to my project, no pip needed. in my opinion, it's more organized than adding the folder or using virtualenv.

What specifically is your question?

i want the generated script to work without the error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

Then don't use a relative import.

Hint:  It's not more organized, and it's more difficult to maintain.
